# XAMPP does not display html paragraph

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

If I open this file with double click (in browser) the last paragraph(the one with id wrongLogin) is visible. But if I open the file with XAMPP on server, the paragraph is invisible. Why?

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url("../images/2.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.panel {
    height: 100px;
    width: 30%;
}

.panel p{
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: center;
    color: red;
}

.panel label{
    color: white;
    font-family: 30px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.panel input{
    width: 50%;
}

#loginButton{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 35%;
}
```

```html
<form action="../php/login.php" method="post">
  <input id = "loginButton" type="image" src ="../images/loginAndRegister.gif" alt="submit">
  <div class = "panel">
    <p> Login </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label> username </label>
    <br>
    <input type = "text" name = "username" required>
    <br>
    <label> password </label>
    <br>
    <input type = "password" name = "password" required>
    <br>
    <p id = "wrongLogin"> Incorrect username or password </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

And down I added the CSS. When I try to open the file in google I can see the paragraph. Only when I open it in XAMPP it gets invisible.

Comment: what is your file extension?

Comment: It should be invisible until the username and password are checked in your php. Use right-click and "inspect" to view if there is some style added to this paragraph

Comment: @bron It is added. for the id wrongLogin the color is set to red

Comment: @KunalRaut My file extension is html

Comment: Can we see your stylesheet `login.css`?

Comment: @DannyXCII I added it just now.

Comment: Doesn't seem anything wrong with your code that I can see - the paragraph shows up in red as expected - presumably this is a XAMPP issue. Is the rest of your CSS working on your localhost?

Comment: @DannyXCII Yes. Everything.